# How to Bulk index in Elastic Search using the Python API

Tags: python, mongodb, elasticsearch

I am trying to bulk insert a lot of documents into elastic search using the Python API.

```
import elasticsearch
from pymongo import MongoClient

es = elasticsearch.Elasticsearch()

def index_collection(db, collection, fields, host='localhost', port=27017):
    conn = MongoClient(host, port)
    coll = conn[db][collection]
    cursor = coll.find({}, fields=fields, timeout=False)
    print "Starting Bulk index of {} documents".format(cursor.count())

    def action_gen():
        """
        Generator to use for bulk inserts
        """
        for n, doc in enumerate(cursor):

            op_dict = {
                '_index': db.lower(),
                '_type': collection,
                '_id': int('0x' + str(doc['_id']), 16),
            }
            doc.pop('_id')
            op_dict['_source'] = doc
            yield op_dict

    res = bulk(es, action_gen(), stats_only=True)
    print res
```

The documents come from a Mongodb collection and I amusing the function above to do the bulk indexing according to the way explained in the docs.

the bulk indexing goes on filling elastic search with thousands of empty documents. Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did your index already exist in ES?  If so, are there any mappings defined for it (is it at all possible that the documents coming out of Mongo don't fit the mapping)?

Comment: Your code works for me. Perhaps your bug is data specific. Care to give a minimal example?

Answer (score 2):

I've never seen the bulk data put together that way, especially what you're doing with `"_source"`. There may be a way to get that to work, I don't know off-hand, but when I tried it I got weird results.

If you look at the [bulk api](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html), ES is expecting a meta-data document, then the document to be indexed. So you need two entries in your bulk data list for each document. So maybe something like:

```
import elasticsearch
from pymongo import MongoClient

es = elasticsearch.Elasticsearch()

def index_collection(db, collection, fields, host='localhost', port=27017):
    conn = MongoClient(host, port)
    coll = conn[db][collection]
    cursor = coll.find({}, fields=fields, timeout=False)
    print "Starting Bulk index of {} documents".format(cursor.count())

    bulk_data = []

    for n, doc in enumerate(cursor):

        bulk_data.append({
            '_index': db.lower(),
            '_type': collection,
            '_id': int('0x' + str(doc['_id']), 16),
        })
        bulk_data.append(doc)

    es.bulk(index=index_name,body=bulk_data,refresh=True)
```

I didn't try to run that code, though. Here is a script I know works, that you can play with, if it helps:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

es_client = Elasticsearch(hosts = [{ "host" : "localhost", "port" : 9200 }])

index_name = "test_index"

if es_client.indices.exists(index_name):
    print("deleting '%s' index..." % (index_name))
    print(es_client.indices.delete(index = index_name, ignore=[400, 404]))

print("creating '%s' index..." % (index_name))
print(es_client.indices.create(index = index_name))

bulk_data = []

for i in range(4):
    bulk_data.append({
        "index": {
            "_index": index_name, 
            "_type": 'doc', 
            "_id": i
        }
    })
    bulk_data.append({ "idx": i })

print("bulk indexing...")
res = es_client.bulk(index=index_name,body=bulk_data,refresh=True)
print(res)

print("results:")
for doc in es_client.search(index=index_name)['hits']['hits']:
    print(doc)
```

Comment: It may work but for my use case, I don't want to load all my data into a list in memory, before I index it, hence the generator function. The documentation led me to the code I posted: https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.org/en/master/helpers.html#helpers

Comment: @SloanAhrens OP is using the helper version of `bulk`, which expects something a bit different than the standard Bulk API.